# cannot load such file -- bcrypt_ext (LoadError) on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x64-mingw32] and rails 5.1.4. I am getting following error when i run `rails s` command.

```
rails s
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require': cannot load such file -- bcrypt_ext (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11-x64-mingw32/lib/bcrypt.rb:16:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11-x64-mingw32/lib/bcrypt.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0.pre.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:83:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0.pre.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:83:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0.pre.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:78:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0.pre.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:78:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0.pre.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:67:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0.pre.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:67:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0.pre.2/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
        from E:/Rauf Personal Data/work/rails/shine/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:133:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:133:in `block in perform'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `perform'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I have almost tried every solution but i am unable to resolve this issue. Can any body please help me to sort out this issue. I already tried following:

Firstly uninstall bcrypt and bcrypt-ruby by running these two commands:
gem uninstall bcrypt and gem uninstall bcrypt-ruby
Install it again with gem install bcrypt --platform=ruby
In your Gemfile write gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.5', :require => 'bcrypt'
Run bundle install

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have managed to solve this issue by adding following line in the Gemfile....

```
gem 'bcrypt', git: 'https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby.git', :require => 'bcrypt'
```

Answer (score 1):

After trying several methods, the above worked for me:
1) Stop all rails servers.
2) Add : gem 'bcrypt', git: 'https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby.git', :require => 'bcrypt' to the gemfile.
3) bundle install.

Comment: Thanks again. For a beginner like me you guys are pure gold.